# Webcam for chromebook, anyway to change its video source?

Tags: google-chrome

Does anyone know of a app, or extension that i can use to put a picture over my webcam on chromebook, i have tried manycam, but to no avail it simply does not show up as an available video source. If anyone could help me out, or knows of something that will work, that will be greatly appreciated.